# How to make view clickable when the view is out of parent view bounds in Android?

Tags: android

I would like to make half of FAB outside of its parent view, just like the [FAB in Google Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nqbi.jpg). I used setTranslationY to offset the view, then it causes only lower half of the FAB is clickable, but I want the entire button to be clickable. I think the problem is related to touch area, but the parent view can not dispatch touch event to the button since parent view doesn't cover the area.

I've checked the layout of Google Maps via hierarchy viewer, and the FAB in Google Maps is obviously inside the sliding panel, also set the translationY to make it be out of parent bounds, but the entire button is clickable. How to achieve that?

layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Set button offset

```
int fabOffset = -getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.support.design.R.dimen.design_fab_size_normal) / 2;
mButtonAdd.setTranslationY(fabOffset);
```

Comment: Please elaborate with some code or some thing with which someone can have more idea of what are you trying to do.

Comment: Hi @Raúl , I've updated the description. Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem? I'm stuck on the same issue.